# Regular expression for numeric only value without decimal places

Tags: java

Regular expression for numeric only value in java without decimal places, or if decimal places are present only 1-9.0 or 1-9.00 is acceptable.

Eg: 12.00, 12.0 and 12 are acceptable but 12.12 or after decimal point other than 0 digit is not acceptable. Negative value is not acceptable either.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: What about more digits, e.g. 12.000?

Comment: Why? Why are .0 and .00 acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the number of zeros, as long as the are only zeros use this:

```
[\d]+[\.[0]+]?
```

If you want specifically to allow one or two zeros use this:

```
[\d]+[\.0|\.00]?
```

Comment: Uri, although your answer is correct and I up-voted it I would like to note that in this case OP has not demonstrated even minimal effort to solve his problem and therefore according to SO rules we should not answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

use this to test pattern like  `10` `10.0` `10.00`

```
    String s="12.00"; //your string to test
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(.(0|00))?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();
```

If you want to allow any amount of `0` like `10.00000..00` after point then

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(.(0+))?");
```

Comment: Note that this pattern also matches the empty string